# How to hide the first two div using css?

Tags: html, css

Here is my page content

```
<div class="entry-content">
<div class="gv-grid">
    <div class="gv-grid-col-1-1 gv-left">

        <form class="gv-widget-search gv-search-vertical" method="get" action="https://www.mypage.com/test/">


            <div class="gv-search-box">
                <div class="gv-search">
                    <label for="gv_search_11">Tìm kiếm</label>
                    <p><input name="gv_search" id="gv_search_11" value="" type="text"></p>
                </div>
            </div>      <div class="gv-search-box gv-search-box-submit">
                <input name="mode" value="all" type="hidden">
                <input class="button gv-search-button" id="gv_search_button_11" value="Search" type="submit">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="gv-grid-col-1-2 gv-left">
    </div>
    <div class="gv-grid-col-1-2 gv-right">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="gv-table-container gv-container">
    <table class="gv-table-view">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th id="gv-field-1-2" class="gv-field-1-2" style=""><span class="gv-field-label"><a href="/test/?sort=2&amp;dir=asc" class="gv-sort icon gv-icon-caret-up-down"></a>&nbsp;Cần mua hộ</span></th>
                <th id="gv-field-1-6" class="gv-field-1-6" style=""><span class="gv-field-label"><a href="/test/?sort=6&amp;dir=asc" class="gv-sort icon gv-icon-caret-up-down"></a>&nbsp;Tiền công</span></th>
                <th id="gv-field-1-15" class="gv-field-1-15" style=""><span class="gv-field-label"><a href="/test/?sort=15&amp;dir=asc" class="gv-sort icon gv-icon-caret-up-down"></a>&nbsp;Nơi mua</span></th>
                <th id="gv-field-1-5" class="gv-field-1-5" style=""><span class="gv-field-label"><a href="/test/?sort=5&amp;dir=asc" class="gv-sort icon gv-icon-caret-up-down"></a>&nbsp;Nơi giao</span></th>
                <th id="gv-field-1-4" class="gv-field-1-4" style=""><span class="gv-field-label"><a href="/test/?sort=4&amp;dir=desc" class="gv-sort icon gv-icon-sort-desc"></a>&nbsp;Giao đồ trước</span></th>
                <th id="gv-field-1-entry_link" class="gv-field-1-entry_link" style=""><span class="gv-field-label">Link</span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr class="alt">
                <td id="gv-field-1-2" class="gv-field-1-2">CEZANNE Lasting Lip Color N 402</td>
                <td id="gv-field-1-6" class="gv-field-1-6">80 000</td>
                <td id="gv-field-1-15" class="gv-field-1-15">Nhật Bản</td>
                <td id="gv-field-1-5" class="gv-field-1-5">Hà Nội</td>
                <td id="gv-field-1-4" class="gv-field-1-4">14/04/2016</td>
                <td id="gv-field-1-entry_link" class="gv-field-1-entry_link"><a href="https://www.mypage.com/test/entry/21/?gvid=11">Chi tiết</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th id="gv-field-1-2" class="gv-field-1-2"><span class="gv-field-label"><a href="/test/?sort=2&amp;dir=asc" class="gv-sort icon gv-icon-caret-up-down"></a>&nbsp;Cần mua hộ</span></th>
                <th id="gv-field-1-6" class="gv-field-1-6"><span class="gv-field-label"><a href="/test/?sort=6&amp;dir=asc" class="gv-sort icon gv-icon-caret-up-down"></a>&nbsp;Tiền công</span></th>
                <th id="gv-field-1-15" class="gv-field-1-15"><span class="gv-field-label"><a href="/test/?sort=15&amp;dir=asc" class="gv-sort icon gv-icon-caret-up-down"></a>&nbsp;Nơi mua</span></th>
                <th id="gv-field-1-5" class="gv-field-1-5"><span class="gv-field-label"><a href="/test/?sort=5&amp;dir=asc" class="gv-sort icon gv-icon-caret-up-down"></a>&nbsp;Nơi giao</span></th>
                <th id="gv-field-1-4" class="gv-field-1-4"><span class="gv-field-label"><a href="/test/?sort=4&amp;dir=desc" class="gv-sort icon gv-icon-sort-desc"></a>&nbsp;Giao đồ trước</span></th>
                <th id="gv-field-1-entry_link" class="gv-field-1-entry_link"><span class="gv-field-label">Link</span></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div><!-- end .gv-table-container -->
<div class="gv-grid">
    <div class="gv-grid-col-1-1 gv-left">
    </div>
    <div class="gv-grid-col-1-2 gv-left">
    </div>
    <div class="gv-grid-col-1-2 gv-right">
    </div>
</div>

<input class="gravityview-view-id" value="11" type="hidden">

<div class="gv-grid">
    <div class="gv-grid-col-1-1 gv-left">

        <form class="gv-widget-search gv-search-vertical" method="get" action="https://www.mypage.com/test/">


            <div class="gv-search-box">
                <div class="gv-search">
                    <label for="gv_search_7770">Tìm kiếm</label>
                    <p><input name="gv_search" id="gv_search_7770" value="" type="text"></p>
                </div>
            </div>      <div class="gv-search-box gv-search-box-submit">
                <input name="mode" value="all" type="hidden">
                <input class="button gv-search-button" id="gv_search_button_7770" value="Search" type="submit">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="gv-grid-col-1-2 gv-left">
    </div>
    <div class="gv-grid-col-1-2 gv-right">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="gv-list-container gv-container">

    <div id="gv_list_30" class="gv-list-view">



        <div class="gv-list-view-title">

            <h3 id="gv-field-1-custom" class="gv-field-1-custom"><b>Ga Cong Nghiep</b> cần mua <b>Giày zara kid size 37</b> bán tại <b>Tây Ban Nha</b></h3>
        </div>



        <div class="gv-grid gv-list-view-content">

            <div class="gv-grid-col-1-3 gv-list-view-content-image"><div id="gv-field-1-14" class="gv-image gv-field-1-14"><a rel="gv-field-1-14-30" class="thickbox" target="_blank" href="https://www.mypage.com/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/1-f9c2348184f1140e486c01fab8f03460/2016/03/1050103050_2_3_1.jpg"><img scale="0" src="https://www.mypage.com/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/1-f9c2348184f1140e486c01fab8f03460/2016/03/1050103050_2_3_1.jpg" alt="Ảnh" class="gv-image gv-field-id-14" width="250"></a></div></div><div class="gv-grid-col-2-3 gv-list-view-content-description">
                <div id="gv-field-1-custom" class="gv-field-1-custom">
                    <h4><span class="gv-field-label"></span></h4><p>
                        Nơi giao hàng: Lạng Sơn<br>
                        Tiền hàng: 25.95 EUR<br>
                        Tiền công : 150,000 VND<br>
                        (Có thể mặc cả tiền công)
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="https://www.mypage.com/test/entry/30/"><button>Chi tiết</button></a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>


    <div id="gv_list_23" class="gv-list-view">



        <div class="gv-list-view-title">

            <h3 id="gv-field-1-custom" class="gv-field-1-custom"><b>Nguyễn Yên</b> cần mua <b>3 hộp kem đánh răng</b> bán tại <b>Nhật Bản</b></h3>
        </div>



        <div class="gv-grid gv-list-view-content">

            <div class="gv-grid-col-1-3 gv-list-view-content-image"><div id="gv-field-1-14" class="gv-image gv-field-1-14"><a rel="gv-field-1-14-23" class="thickbox" target="_blank" href="https://www.mypage.com/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/1-f9c2348184f1140e486c01fab8f03460/2016/03/kem-danh-rang.jpg"><img scale="0" src="https://www.mypage.com/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/1-f9c2348184f1140e486c01fab8f03460/2016/03/kem-danh-rang.jpg" alt="Ảnh" class="gv-image gv-field-id-14" width="250"></a></div></div><div class="gv-grid-col-2-3 gv-list-view-content-description">
                <div id="gv-field-1-custom" class="gv-field-1-custom">
                    <h4><span class="gv-field-label"></span></h4><p>
                        Nơi giao hàng: Hà Nội<br>
                        Tiền hàng: 513 JPY<br>
                        Tiền công : 85,000 VND<br>
                        (Có thể mặc cả tiền công)
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="https://www.mypage.com/test/entry/23/"><button>Chi tiết</button></a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>


    <div id="gv_list_25" class="gv-list-view">



        <div class="gv-list-view-title">

            <h3 id="gv-field-1-custom" class="gv-field-1-custom"><b>Trường Hải Minh</b> cần mua <b>Đồng hồ Casio  WAVECEPTOR WVQ-M410DE-2A2JF</b> bán tại <b>Nhật Bản</b></h3>
        </div>



        <div class="gv-grid gv-list-view-content">

            <div class="gv-grid-col-1-3 gv-list-view-content-image"><div id="gv-field-1-14" class="gv-image gv-field-1-14"><ul class="gv-field-file-uploads gv-field-1-14"><li><a rel="gv-field-1-14-25" class="thickbox" target="_blank" href="https://www.mypage.com/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/1-f9c2348184f1140e486c01fab8f03460/2016/03/51Pj4cBrBpL.jpg"><img scale="0" src="https://www.mypage.com/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/1-f9c2348184f1140e486c01fab8f03460/2016/03/51Pj4cBrBpL.jpg" alt="Ảnh" class="gv-image gv-field-id-14" width="250"></a></li><li><a rel="gv-field-1-14-25" class="thickbox" target="_blank" href="https://www.mypage.com/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/1-f9c2348184f1140e486c01fab8f03460/2016/03/81xcVWtGDyL._UL1500.jpg"><img scale="0" src="https://www.mypage.com/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/1-f9c2348184f1140e486c01fab8f03460/2016/03/81xcVWtGDyL._UL1500.jpg" alt="Ảnh" class="gv-image gv-field-id-14" width="250"></a></li></ul></div></div><div class="gv-grid-col-2-3 gv-list-view-content-description">
                <div id="gv-field-1-custom" class="gv-field-1-custom">
                    <h4><span class="gv-field-label"></span></h4><p>
                        Nơi giao hàng: Hà Nội<br>
                        Tiền hàng: 15,370 JPY<br>
                        Tiền công : 200,000 VND<br>
                        (Có thể mặc cả tiền công)
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="https://www.mypage.com/test/entry/25/"><button>Chi tiết</button></a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>


    <div id="gv_list_21" class="gv-list-view">



        <div class="gv-list-view-title">

            <h3 id="gv-field-1-custom" class="gv-field-1-custom"><b>Nguyễn Hương</b> cần mua <b>CEZANNE Lasting Lip Color N 402</b> bán tại <b>Nhật Bản</b></h3>
        </div>



        <div class="gv-grid gv-list-view-content">

            <div class="gv-grid-col-1-3 gv-list-view-content-image"><div id="gv-field-1-14" class="gv-image gv-field-1-14"><a rel="gv-field-1-14-21" class="thickbox" target="_blank" href="https://www.mypage.com/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/1-f9c2348184f1140e486c01fab8f03460/2016/03/N402.jpg"><img scale="0" src="https://www.mypage.com/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/1-f9c2348184f1140e486c01fab8f03460/2016/03/N402.jpg" alt="Ảnh" class="gv-image gv-field-id-14" width="250"></a></div></div><div class="gv-grid-col-2-3 gv-list-view-content-description">
                <div id="gv-field-1-custom" class="gv-field-1-custom">
                    <h4><span class="gv-field-label"></span></h4><p>
                        Nơi giao hàng: Hà Nội<br>
                        Tiền hàng: 518 JPY<br>
                        Tiền công : 80,000 VND<br>
                        (Có thể mặc cả tiền công)
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="https://www.mypage.com/test/entry/21/"><button>Chi tiết</button></a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>

</div>
<div class="gv-grid">
    <div class="gv-grid-col-1-1 gv-left">
    </div>
    <div class="gv-grid-col-1-2 gv-left">
    </div>
    <div class="gv-grid-col-1-2 gv-right">
    </div>
</div>

<input class="gravityview-view-id" value="7770" type="hidden">
```

I want to use css to hide the first two div of `.entry-content`.
How can I do it?

Comment: More detail needed. Hide when, how?

Comment: Seriously, 4 gold badge and 46 others still asking question like this..??

Comment: Have a look at `:nth-child` or sibling selectors.

Comment: Guyz can you please stop posting answers for this question as its as simple as to say snow is white.. please don't spam on site.. and someone please close this question..thanx and sorry for being rude but for stop spam plz.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show/hide div using css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443172/show-hide-div-using-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do following way using **[:first-child](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-child/)** css:

```css
.entry-content div:first-child, .entry-content div:first-child + div {
   display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-content">
  <div class="gv-grid">1</div> 
  <div class="gv-table-container gv-container">2</div> 
  <div class="gv-grid">3</div>
  <div class="gv-table-container gv-container">4</div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

As per you html structure use css like following:

```
.entry-content > div:first-child, .entry-content > div:first-child + div {
   display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Try using the `nth-child` selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672625/how-to-select-first-2-li-elements-using-css):

```css
.entry-content div:nth-child(-n+2){
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-content">
  <div class="gv-grid">1st</div>
  <div class="gv-table-container gv-container">2nd</div>
  <div class="gv-grid">3rd</div>
  <div class="gv-table-container gv-container">4th</div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice  `-n+2 ` , can you cite it ?

Comment: @zan what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="entry-content">
  <div class="gv-grid" style="display: none;">...</div> //HIDE THIS
  <div class=gv-table-container gv-container" style="display: none;">...</div> //HIDE THIS
  <div class="gv-grid">...</div>
  <div class=gv-table-container gv-container">...</div>
</div>
```

`style` tag is embedded CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Simple CSS2.1 version of this uses the *sibling selector*.

```
.gv-grid, .gv-table-container {
  display: none;
}

.gv-grid ~ .gv-grid, .gv-table-container ~ .gv-table-container {
  display: block;
}
```

The way the sibling selector works is that is will fire if an element has an *earlier* sibling that matches.
So the first rule applies to all `.gv-grid` and `.gv-table-container` elements within a shared parent; the subsequent rule will override it for later `.gv-grid` and `.gv-table-container` elements.